# Cygwin is not working while creating image in docker

Tags: image, docker, cygwin, dockerfile

I am new to docker technology.

We are automating build process using make build.

We are creating a image out of dockerfile which should accept shell script(build.sh) as parameter. but it always says build.sh not found.

I tried with various versions of commands inside docker still no luck.

Here is my code for dockerfile:

```
# Install node
RUN apk update && apk add
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
RUN apk add --update curl
RUN mkdir /build

COPY ./build.sh /build
RUN chmod +x /build/build.sh
WORKDIR /build
CMD build/build.sh
```

I am making use of cygwin since I am using windows OS.

Comment: Carefully compare the paths in your COPY, WORKDIR, and RUN commands.  I think it's trying to launch `/build/build/build.sh`.

Comment: Have you checked, when running your docker image, that `/build/build.sh` is actually where you expect it to be?   Does the problem occur when building the image, or running it in a container?  Whatever the problem I don't think it has to do with Cygwin.  I use docker from within a Cygwin shell all the time an it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Its happening while building image.